# How i got the answer 24?

Tags: operator-keyword, increment, prefix

we have a question in our first term examination.

int a=10, b;
b= ++a + ++a;

some pupils said that the answer is 22, some others 23.
but when i did the program i got the answer as 24.
Now i'm confused.
 Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be 23 as far as I'm concerned...

a= 10

with ++a incrementing on access to a versus a++ accessing and then incrementing after returning a.

therefore b = 11 + 12 = 23

this may be helpful for you, although it seems that some languagues can produce different results.. http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/62782

EDIT:

It seems as though different compilers treat the operations differently. In theory it should be 23, but if your compiler handles both ++a operations BEFORE anything else (and not going from left to right as theory would have you do) then your answer would be
b= 12+12 = 24